# Using jQuery to start asynchronous CSS animations

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll

I am trying to achieve an animation on scroll into view. I have made this version that works but it has very long and repetitive code. I tried counting the divs and looping through them, animating them one by one, but it doesn't seem to work very well. Any suggestions? I couldn't find any similar issue anywhere else.

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var scrollTop,
      windowHeight = ($(window).height()) / 2,
      divScrollTop = $("section").offset().top;
    
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (windowHeight + scrollTop >= divScrollTop) {
          setTimeout(function() {
                $(".card:nth-of-type(1)").addClass('animate');
            }, 0);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".card:nth-of-type(2)").addClass('animate');
            }, 300);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".card:nth-of-type(3)").addClass('animate');
            }, 600);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".card:nth-of-type(4)").addClass('animate');
            }, 900);
        }
  });
  
})
```

```css
section {
    margin-top: 100%;
    
  height: 800px;
}
.card {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: all 1s;
  display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes slideUpFadeIn {
  from {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.animate {
  animation: slideUpFadeIn 1s forwards;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I scroll down and the 4 boxes fade in. Can you clarify what the problem is

Comment: The problem is that the jQuery code I'm using to achieve this is very long and repetitive and I was wondering if there was a simpler/shorter solution to this. Like looping through the divs or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the divs using each in jquery. Then delay each of the animations inside the loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var scrollTop,
      windowHeight = ($(window).height()) / 2,
      divScrollTop = $("section").offset().top;
    
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (windowHeight + scrollTop >= divScrollTop) {
            $(".card").each(function(i) {
                $(this).delay(i*300).queue(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('animate').dequeue();
                });
            })
        }
  });
});
```

```css
section {
    margin-top: 100%;
    
  height: 800px;
}
.card {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: all 1s;
  display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes slideUpFadeIn {
  from {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.animate {
  animation: slideUpFadeIn 1s forwards;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```